# Html table data gets duplicated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two Html tables with two JSON data what i am doing is initially i am loading   table with `tableData` which has quantity `0` , in my HTML form i have 3 buttons `save` `load draft` and `edit` on click of `load draft` i am loading some data in table on click of load i am calling `tableDataDraft` which loads some data then again i am clicking edit to edit data

**issue i am facing**

- when i click on edit i am showing that draft data (tableDraft) as well as tableData
- so my issue is when i click data comes into table but gets duplicate like here in my code `1001` comes twice once with its `quantinty` value as `1213.0000` and again as quantity as `0` which i don't want
  i want the values with zero should not come
- and it should come in sequence also like 1001 is at the first place then it should come at first only
- data should not get duplicated

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1000",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S1",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1083",
    "Item Name": "Oma Stick 200gm",
    "Category Name": "Biscuits",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1387",
    "Item Name": "simple Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },


  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  }
]

var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "1213.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1083",
    "Item Name": "Oma Stick 200gm",
    "Category Name": "Biscuits",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },

  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "2596.0000"
  }
]

$("#loadDraft").click(function() {
  addTableDraft(tableDataDraft);
  $("#edit").show();
})

var itemsQuantiry = []; // higliting the error i think

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft, tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Quantity'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry[i]) { // higliting the error i think
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry[i]);
        } else { // higliting the error i think
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)

        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  $(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
    itemsQuantiry[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
  });
}
addTableDraft(tableData);


function editData() { //this function is doing edit work
  var temptable = [];
  $.each(tableDataDraft, function(index) {
    temptable.push(tableDataDraft[index]);
  });
  $.each(tableData, function(index) {
    temptable.push(tableData[index]);
  });
  addTableDraft(temptable)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="edit" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display:none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Edit
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="loadDraft" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Load Draft
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

as there is function editData() which is doing edit work but displaying duplicate data
i don't want data with zero and should display in sequence

any body out here please help

Comment: so basically you're saying you need to delete the existing table contents before loading the new contents?

Comment: @ADyson not that i want to do just mix both data as the are same but quantity is different...want to hide the duplicate values after click of edit, as you see in mu snippet 1001 is repeating i want to show 1001 with the value not with value `0`

Comment: ok so did you try looping through the existing raw data and looking for duplicates before you decide to insert a row? Then you can decide which version to keep and which one to discard. The logic isn't too complex I don't think, you just need a bit of extra code to do that test.

Comment: @ADyson i haven't  had idea about that i want to check when edit click,on editData function there should be some code to edit

Comment: ok well that should be the first thing to do. Before you push an item from `tableData` into `temptable`, check in `temptable` if an item with the same ID already exists, and then decide if you want to over-write it instead of add a new item. And then after that you can research how to sort arrays of objects using Javascript (you can google lots of ideas/examples, you don't need us to repeat that here)

Comment: P.S. It's not really clear to me why you have separate `addTable` and `addTableDraft` functions? The data structure is the same in each case, so surely the process of adding the data is identical? The only difference maybe is at the end when you decide to show different buttons or something. I haven't looked in detail but at a glance it appears probably 90% of that code is duplicated for no reason

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you have extracted a value from an input and converted the value into a real number. You are aware that form elements cannot store real numbers they store strings, even the numbers are stings "5" does not equal 5.

Comment: @ADyson can you help me with some code please..i have also edited my code with one function only

Comment: @zer00ne i am just using `autocomplete = on` to store values until page reloads..and at my back end i will check the variable type and convert them

Comment: I don't think you need my help. You know how to write a loop through an array...it's simple, just loop the `temptable` array and check each item until you come to one with the ID the same as the one you are about to add. If you don't find such an item, go ahead and push the new item. If you do find one, then you can examine the quantity field of that item and decide if you are going replace the draft data with the new data, or not. I have explained the logic...now it's not difficult code compared to the kind of code you have already been writing above. So try it.If you get stuck then ask again

Comment: @ADyson now having only one function with passing two parameters,the above work is done by some one else thats why i am facing issues, i am very new to these things

Comment: I don't think the function needs to accept two parameters...it's unclear how that would help. You process the data, then pass the final data to the function so it can draw the table. Separate the data _processing_ part from the data _display_ part. When you are only displaying draft data, no processing is really needed, so just pass in the draft data. When you are editing, then you need to run the logic I described above to combine the datasets before passing it to the drawing function. (And of course you need to clear the table cells before drawing new ones)

Comment: @ADyson data is of two type one has quantity as 0 other has some values rather then 0

Comment: yes I've already addressed that - when you are inserting, if you find an existing item with the same ID, then you need to check `quantity` in the new item. And then if your new item has `quantity` of `0`, as per your stated requirement you don't want to insert that item into your data, and you want to keep the draft item instead. Simple enough...what's the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187730/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you add the new items to the table (after clicking on "edit"), for each new item you need to check whether an item with the same ID already exists in the current table data. If it does, and the item you're adding has "quantity" of "0", then the item must not be added.

You can achieve this by looping through the existing data and comparing it to each new item you are wanting to add.

See the modified "editData()" function in the example below:

```js
var tableData = [{
    "Item Code": "1000",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S1",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1083",
    "Item Name": "Oma Stick 200gm",
    "Category Name": "Biscuits",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1387",
    "Item Name": "simple Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  },


  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "0"
  }
]

var tableDataDraft = [{
    "Item Code": "1001",
    "Item Name": "Coffee-S",
    "Category Name": "Beverages",
    "Quantity": "1213.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1083",
    "Item Name": "Oma Stick 200gm",
    "Category Name": "Biscuits",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },
  {
    "Item Code": "1388",
    "Item Name": "Bakala Bhath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "1478.0000"
  },

  {
    "Item Code": "1389",
    "Item Name": "Bisibelebath",
    "Category Name": "Bhath",
    "Quantity": "2596.0000"
  }
]

$("#loadDraft").click(function() {
  addTableDraft(tableDataDraft);
  $("#edit").show();
})

var itemsQuantiry = []; // higliting the error i think

function addTableDraft(tableDataDraft, tableData) {
  var col = Object.keys(tableDataDraft[0]);
  var countNum = col.filter(i => !isNaN(i)).length;
  var num = col.splice(0, countNum);
  col = col.concat(num);
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
    tr.classList.add("text-center");
    tr.classList.add("head")
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < tableDataDraft.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    tr.classList.add("item-row");
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
      hiddenField.style.display = "none";
      var tabledata = tableDataDraft[i][col[j]];
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Code'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Code');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Item Name'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        tabCell.innerHTML = tabledata;
        hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'Item_Name');
        hiddenField.setAttribute('value', tabledata);
        tabCell.appendChild(hiddenField);
      }
      if (tableDataDraft[i]['Quantity'] === tableDataDraft[i][col[j]]) {
        var quantityField = document.createElement("input");
        quantityField.style.border = "none";
        quantityField.style["text-align"] = "right";
        quantityField.setAttribute("name", "Quantity_field");
        quantityField.setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
        if (itemsQuantiry[i]) { // higliting the error i think
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", itemsQuantiry[i]);
        } else { // higliting the error i think
          quantityField.setAttribute("value", tabledata);
        }
        quantityField.setAttribute("index", i);
        quantityField.setAttribute("type", "number");
        quantityField.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.value=''");
        quantityField.setAttribute("required", "required");
        quantityField.classList.add("dataReset");
        quantityField.toLocaleString('en-IN');
        tabCell.appendChild(quantityField);
      }

      if (j > 1)

        tabCell.classList.add("text-right");
    }
  }
  var divContainer = document.getElementById("HourlysalesSummary");
  divContainer.innerHTML = "";
  divContainer.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  $(".dataReset").on("change", function(e) {
    itemsQuantiry[$(this).attr('index')] = e.target.value;
  });
}
addTableDraft(tableData);


function editData() { //this function is doing edit work 
  var temptable = tableDataDraft;
  $.each(tableData, function(index, obj) {
    var id = obj["Item Code"];
    var addNewData = true;

    //check existing data 
    $.each(temptable, function(idx, obj2) {
      //if the ID matches and the new quantity is 0 then don't add the new item 
      if (obj2["Item Code"] == id && obj["Quantity"] == 0) {
        addNewData = false;
        return false;
      }
    });

    if (addNewData == true) temptable.push(tableData[index]);
  });
  addTableDraft(temptable)

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container" id="divHide">
  <form id="indentForm" autocomplete="on">
    <div class="row position-relative">
    </div>
    <hr style="border: 1px solid black">
    <div>
      <button type="button" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="edit" class="commonButton" onclick="editData()" style="display:none">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Edit
    </button>
      <button type="button" id="loadDraft" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fas fa-save"></i>Load Draft
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="w-100" id=HourlysalesSummary></table>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

P.S. Regarding sorting of the array by ID (before displaying it), this is something you can easily research separately. I don't see any need to duplicate existing material on that topic here.